# How to make view scrollable in side view in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to make uiview scrollable in swift 4.

[image]

[image]

I want to make this graycolor view scrollable. I put UIscrollview inside that view but its not working. so any other way to make this view scrollable. Thank You in advance.

Comment: could you show us some code / storyboard please ?

Comment: i edited my question. Add storyboard. @Olympiloutre

Comment: Okay this is not actually how a ScrollView works. You dont put it inside the view you want to be scrollable. Instead, the UIScrollView contains the view that is too big to be displayed 
I suggest you to read : https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7.

Comment: I don't want to make whole view scrollable. Only bottom view make to scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a UITableView instead UIScrollView and put a UIView inside tableview instead of UITableViewCell. It will work fine and It will be scrollable without any hassle .

Comment: Right. Actually problem is this is profile screen. But I want to edit that profile so that I have to edit tableview data. But when we edit tableview Data and scroll screen whole data refresh automatically. I face this issue so I removed Tableview.

Comment: @sohan123 ok So you means say you just want to scroll only gray color. And You want to update profile information with UITextField . Am I right ?

Comment: yes. Beacuse in tableview when we edit textfield and scroll the tableview , edit textfield content remove. and look like previous one. So I remove tableview

Comment: this is the best solution for my long term concern

Answer (score 0):

You UIOutlet seems fine. You just need to do one thing, make your scrollview's view to equal height and width to scrollview's parent view and set height priority to 250. 
Done your view gonna scroll now.

Comment: but how can I increse the height of parent view?

Comment: Click on ViewController goto Size Inspector from there set simulated size freedom instead of fixed. Now good to go you can set whatever size you want to set.